# Why do robots use the word "affirmative" to agree?

Tags: word-choice

In the Terminator 2 movie, the human character asks the terminator not to use the word **affirmative**.

> John Connor: No, no, no, no. You gotta listen to the way people talk. You don't say "**affirmative**" or some shit like that.

Again, the robot in the movie **Chappie (2015)** also uses this word.

Why do so many robots use the word "affirmative" to agree with a statement?

Comment: Because that's the way robots speak.  Just like how Data doesn't use contractions.

Comment: However, backwoods robots say "negatory" instead of "negative."

Comment: [A relevant educational film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IPAOxrH7Ro)

Answer (score 2):

If you use "affirmative" in place of "yes or I agree", people will notice you are quite different from normal people. That's why robots use it because they are not human beings.

Actually, affirmative is one of many **"Procedure Words / Prowords in short"** mainly used by almost all in the military and pilots in aviation industry for radio communication to facilitate it by conveying information in a standard form. They are using them because "Procedure Words" are much clearer in terms of pronunciation and message delivery.

In extremely noisy circumstances where helicopters, figher jets, and bombers are flying, tanks are passing by, and gunshots are fired, there are not better words than "procedure words" to communicate with.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_word

The link above will help you understand more about them. I believe you heard many of them in war movies or TV shows.